# Deep learning - cost function increases for my training set, Theano

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network

I'm trying to train an extremely simple neural network, it has 2 hidden layers (for example) with 5 neurons each.

For some reason, my cost function (chosen to be cross entropy, but doesn't really matter) is always increasing for a certain dataset.

This is my code -

```
import theano_net as N
from load import mnist
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
import numpy as np
import cv2

def floatX(X):
    return np.asarray(X,dtype=theano.config.floatX)

def init_weights(shape):
    return theano.shared(floatX(np.random.randn(*shape)*0.01))

def appendGD(params, grad, step):
    updates = []
    for p,g in zip(params,grad):
        updates.append([p, p - (g * step)])
    return updates

def model(X,w1,w2,wo):
    h0 = X
    z1 = T.dot(h0, w1.T)  ## n on m1
    h1 = T.nnet.sigmoid(z1)

    z2 = T.dot(h1, w2.T)  ## n on m2
    h2 = T.nnet.sigmoid(z2)

    zo = T.dot(h2, wo.T)

    return T.nnet.softmax(zo)

numOfTrainPics = 4872
numOfTestPics = 382
numOfPixels = 40000
numOfLabels = 6

trX = np.zeros((numOfTrainPics,numOfPixels))
trY = np.zeros((numOfTrainPics,numOfLabels))
teX = np.zeros((numOfTestPics,numOfPixels))
teY = np.zeros((numOfTestPics,numOfLabels))

for i in range(1,4873): #generate trX and trY
    img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Oria\\Desktop\\Semester B\\Computer Vision Cornel 2016\\Train\\Train\\%s.jpg' %(i))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    img = np.reshape(img,(1,numOfPixels))
    trX[i-1,:] = img
    if(i < 1330):
        trY[i-1,0] = 1
    if(i > 1329)&(i < 1817):
        trY[i-1,1] = 1
    if(i > 1816)&(i < 2389):
        trY[i-1,2] = 1
    if(i > 2388)&(i < 3043):
        trY[i-1,3] = 1
    if(i > 3042)&(i < 4438):
        trY[i-1,4] = 1
    if(i > 4437)&(i < 4873):
        trY[i-1,5] = 1
for i in range(1,383):
    img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Oria\\Desktop\\Semester B\\Computer Vision Cornel 2016\\Test\\Test\\%s.jpg' %(i))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    img = np.reshape(img,(1,numOfPixels))
    teX[i-1,:] = img
    if(i < 59):
        teY[i-1,0] = 1
    if(i > 58)&(i < 120):
        teY[i-1,1] = 1
    if(i > 119)&(i < 185):
        teY[i-1,2] = 1
    if(i > 184)&(i < 261):
        teY[i-1,3] = 1
    if(i > 260)&(i < 326):
        teY[i-1,4] = 1
    if(i > 325)&(i < 383):
        teY[i-1,5] = 1
print "matrices generated"
###

x = T.fmatrix()
y = T.fmatrix()
step = 0.1
m1 = 5
m2 = 5
w1 = init_weights((m1, numOfPixels))
w2 = init_weights((m2, m1))
wo = init_weights((numOfLabels, m2))

temp = model(x, w1, w2, wo)

predictions = T.argmax(temp, axis= 1)

cost = T.mean(T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(temp, y))

params = [w1, w2, wo]
gradient = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt = params)
update = appendGD(params, gradient, step)

train = theano.function(inputs = [x,y], outputs = cost, updates = update, allow_input_downcast=True)
predict = theano.function(inputs=[x],outputs=[predictions],allow_input_downcast=True)

for i in range(10000):
    for start, end in zip(range(0,len(trX),241),range(241,len(trX),241)):
        cost = train(trX[start:end], trY[start:end])
    print cost
```

And for the trX,trY that I'm loading in this code, my cost function is always increasing.

However, when I ran the same code but where trX and trY are from MNIST dataset, it is working correctly and the cost function is decreasing.

I don't understand why this is the case and how to fix it.

A clue might be that when I looked at say, the first row of trX of the mnist dataset (the first picture), it was a very sparse matrix, and the non zero elements were all between 0 and 1.

```
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.01176471
  0.07058824  0.07058824  0.07058824  0.49411765  0.53333333  0.68627451
  0.10196078  0.65098039  1.          0.96862745  0.49803922  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.11764706  0.14117647  0.36862745
  0.60392157  0.66666667  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.88235294  0.6745098   0.99215686  0.94901961  0.76470588
  0.25098039  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.19215686
  0.93333333  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.98431373  0.36470588  0.32156863
  0.32156863  0.21960784  0.15294118  0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.07058824  0.85882353  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.77647059  0.71372549  0.96862745  0.94509804
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.31372549  0.61176471
  0.41960784  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.80392157  0.04313725  0.
  0.16862745  0.60392157  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.05490196  0.00392157  0.60392157  0.99215686  0.35294118  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.54509804  0.99215686  0.74509804  0.00784314
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.04313725  0.74509804  0.99215686
  0.2745098   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.1372549
  0.94509804  0.88235294  0.62745098  0.42352941  0.00392157  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.31764706  0.94117647  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.46666667  0.09803922
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.17647059  0.72941176  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.58823529  0.10588235  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.0627451   0.36470588
  0.98823529  0.99215686  0.73333333  0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.97647059  0.99215686  0.97647059  0.25098039  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.18039216  0.50980392
  0.71764706  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.81176471  0.00784314  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.15294118  0.58039216  0.89803922
  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.98039216  0.71372549  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.09411765  0.44705882  0.86666667  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.78823529  0.30588235  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.09019608  0.25882353  0.83529412  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.77647059  0.31764706  0.00784314  0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.07058824  0.67058824  0.85882353  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.76470588  0.31372549  0.03529412  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.21568627  0.6745098   0.88627451  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686
  0.99215686  0.95686275  0.52156863  0.04313725  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.53333333  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686  0.83137255
  0.52941176  0.51764706  0.0627451   0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
```

When I look at my trX however with the database im loading in my code, trX[0] is mostly non zero with elements between 0 and 255.

I just want to train a neural network on my database. It shouldn't be too difficult and the code is proven to work with MNIST. I just dont understand how to actually load my dataset correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to normalize your input data to the [0, 1] or [-1, 1] range, as you see this is already done in the MNIST dataset you have.
Without normalization, training a neural network is much more difficult.

You can do this easily by either substracting the mean of your dataset, and dividing by the standard deviation or just do min-max normalization, which will give [0, 1] range.

For 8-bit per channel images, you can just divide each pixel by 255 to get [0, 1] range, which is normally enough to get a NN trained, but not always.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that it is not about "being more difficult", but simply all the heuristics used in NN, such as parameters of the distributions used to initialize weights are hand crafted for input in [0,1] range. Outside of this bounds, one will nearly always end up outside reasonable range of input values of the activation functions

Comment: And this normalization doesn't keep inputs in [-1, 1] range.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Actually is approximately [-1, 1] range.

Comment: Approximately?. If you e.g. normalize some Normal Distribiution then you will get Standard Normal Distribiution. Is up to you if this distribiution is approximately in [-1, 1] range.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Ah yeah you are right, it normalizes but not to a predefined range. I will update the answer.

Comment: @lejlot It is more difficult because then neurons will learn at different rates, dictated by each input's scale.

Comment: @Matias, with modern method like Adam or Rmsprop etc. it is not true, as they adapt well to such simple issues. The actual problem lies in the initialization only.

Comment: In fact data normalisation may speed up your training and lead to better generalisation due to fact that every variable is treated as equally important.

Comment: @lejlot Yes I agree with that, but this is not the case here, the OP is using plain SGD. Also batch normalization would help in the same way.